# Google 2-Step verification Email in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

I have gmail account which has 2-step verification enabled. If I want to use that email in my MVC Web App in Web.config then how should I use it? Should I disable 2-step verification of google account?

Comment: "want to use that email in my MVC Web App in Web.config" To do what? login? Send an email via code? Unclear question.

Comment: to send email to users using that email

Comment: well if the app password does not work then yes disable it or make a new account for app sending emails.

Comment: app password worked, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to accept the answer below as it was  ppthetech who mentioned app password and the link about it

Answer (score 0):

When you have enabled TFA on your Google account, you can generate app passwords for these kind of situations. App passwords are generated for a single purpose, and you typically will only use them for this application.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Most TFA solutions support the concept of app passwords.

Comment: Thanks for help. Once I generate App Password. Do I replace Password section in Web.Config with this new 16 digit password?

Comment: Yes, you can just use the app password, instead of your 'normal' password.